Power BI Cumulative Total: Role of Colum in ALL-Filter and Format of Date-Colum
I created a bar chart, in which the x-axis displayed the months and the y-axis displayed a measure on number of persons fulfilling  a criteria.
For fulfilling the criteria, it is checked in my measures whether a cumulative amount was reached by the end of the respective month, such that the number of persons fulfilling the criteria should monotonically increase over time.
I ran into two types of problems that I was able to solve but do not fully understand where they might have emerged from. Hence, my question would be whether anyone has suggestions on the following two problems that I ran into. The details of the setup and functioning version come below the two questions.

When writing the date-column in the first ALL-position (as is shown in guides on creating cumulative totals, see formulation below here), the measure returned separately the amounts within each month instead of the cumulative total.

Criteria = CALCULATE(ROUND(SUM('Table Amount'[Amount]),0), FILTER(ALL('Table Amount**'[Date]**), 'Table Amount'[Date] <= MAX('Table Amount'[Date])))

When adding the month-component at the end of the date-columns in the filter-condition, it returned the final cumulative total for all months equally.

Criteria = CALCULATE(ROUND(SUM('Table Amount'[Amount]),0), FILTER(ALL('Table Amount'), 'Table Amount'[Date].[Month] <= MAX('Table Amount'[Date].[Month])))
In the bar chart I have on the x-axis a month variable that derives the month from a table with amount information at person level.
Dateinchart = IF(MONTH('Table Amount'[Date]) <= [Datefilter], 'Table Amount'[Date].[Month])
--> The Datefilter extracts the MAX('Table Amount'[Date])
In the bar chart I displayed a measures, which using SUMX sums the number of persons fulfilling the criteria. For the criteria, whether the amount was fulfilled, I have as now functioning version the following formulation:
Criteria = CALCULATE(ROUND(SUM('Table Amount'[Amount]),0), FILTER(ALL('Table Amount'), 'Table Amount'[Date] <= MAX('Table Amount'[Date])))
